# How do I remove this light bulb to replace it?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

Sorry if this has been asked before - but I cannot figure out how to remove this light bulb to replace it.  Any suggestions so I don't break it?  thanks!

[image: light bulb]

Comment: There's no light bulb there.  That's an LED. LEDs are semiconductor, and don't burn out.   From the look of it, it's an integral LED.   You'd remove the fixture using the normal method for doing that.

Comment: Thank you.  Of the 4 in our kitchen, 2 are now not working.   We have owned the home since 2016, and I haven't had any problems until a few months ago.   I will research how to remove an integral LED....

Comment: pull the whole thing out (outermost ring); they are spring loaded and might be a bit snug, but they pop out and will also pop back in; a little scary the first time, you've nothing to lose.

Comment: Simply push hardish with both thumbs on the glass, and make a left turn motion.  It should turn. One turn is done it drops right down

Comment: The outermost ring does not appear to be spring-loaded..   I will try again.         And there is no glass on the cover of the LED - so I have tried to push hardish on the rim of the inner ring (just the light) and rotate to the left, but it won't budge (and I can't get much of a grip).  But I will try again...

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the fixture's electronic driver, then.  It's a module stuffed with electronic components that converts AC power to the correct DC voltage *and current* to drive the LEDs.  It's part of the fixture usually.  So the goal becomes "remove the fixture and see what you're looking at".

Comment: I have done some image searched on it. It looks very much like: "Designers Fountain Directional Gimbal LED Trim lights". If so, there is no removable bulb. They claim 20 year life so you "never have to change it". Of interest, if you do the same search, there are images of the whole unit uninstalled so you can see the 2 springs and how they hook behind the ceiling drywall. You should be able to grab the WHOLE unit and pull down - don't yank right out... it will slide out and there is a hook on the spring ends... you want to squeeze the springs in to clear the hook. Looks like plug-and-play

Comment: Thank you all for your help!!  Yes, I think this is the Designers Fountain 4" LED Downlight Gimbal...  I can't get the whole unit out easily but I will likely have to replace at least 2 of these anyway (so I will wait before I pull it out).  And now the third is flickering! Grr.. Might be best to replace all 4 of them at the same time.    Thanks again all - have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure it's defective? LED lamps tend to last a long while, and the circuit to it is more likely to be the cause of an issue.

Second, try pressing gently on the inner ring and turning counterclockwise. The lamp might have a [GU-type bi-pin base](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bi-pin_lamp_base) or it might have an [Edison screw base](https://www.jkllamps.com/images/400x400/Z-PAR38-WW-120.jpg). The GU-base requires only a fraction of a turn to remove, but the Edison-base needs several revolutions.

Third, try pulling gently on the outer ring; this may be held in place by a spring. If the lamp drops a bit, look behind it for access.

Finally, the lamp may *not* be removable from the fixture; you'd need to replace the whole fixture, instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  So two are now not working. We have owned the house since 2016 and have only started having issues (one stopped working a few months ago, and the second one last week).  They are all on the same wall switch so I assume they are all on the same circuit, so that is likely not the issue.

Comment: I can't move the inner ring at all...    and I can't pull the outer ring out either.

Comment: ok so why would one ever install a light like this if it can't be removed?  ugh.  I was trying to avoid calling an electrician.  :(

Comment: But thank you for you help.

Comment: They're supposed to last forever, which is why they are hard to replace.

Comment: @MiaBanks This isn't an electrician job, more of a lighting guy job.   The LEDs don't fail but their power supplies (DC drivers) sometimes do, especially if they are cheaply made.